# Merge multiple choice questions output

Tags: excel, survey

I'm asked to analyse data from a survey that includes questions where the respondent can check/uncheck boxes if they apply. For example: Which cultural activities do you participate in?

- classical music;
- opera;
- ballet;
- comedy;
- etc.

The results appear in Yes/No form. Every category is a new column.
Is there a way to combine these resuls into one variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a sample or screenshot of you spreadsheet and the expected result?

Comment: It would also be useful to see what you have tried and have an explanation how the result fails to match expectations